# Matrix multiplication on an upper/lower triangular matrix

Tags: c++, math, r, algorithms

I am a statistician working on DNA datasets.  I am writing an R package, and I will routinely need to perform matrix multiplication on upper-triangular (sparse) matrices that have **hundreds-of-millions** of columns/rows.

I will be multiplying these matrices by low-pass and high-pass filters.  For example:

[image]

Note that when multiplying the right and center, only the first two rows of the 'a' matrix need to be multiplied by the first column of the down-sampler, as the rest all have zeros in the first two entries.

Similarly, when premultiplying the down-sampler with the 'A' matrix, only the first row needs to be multiplied by the first column, as subsequent rows will be multiplying by zeros only.

Clearly when dealing with *massive* matrices, these unnecessary operations will add time to the calculation that could otherwise be avoided.

My question is:  **Is there a *'Forward multiplication'* function for upper triangular matrices** in either the `R` packages `Matrix` or `c++` (which I can implement in `Rcpp`) that will avoid the unnecessary row/column operations that are not needed?